# Assign ID to options in a drop down box and pass as IPN variable

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a rather complicated issue that I am trying to solve in PHP and Paypal's IPN codes..

I am selling one product which has multiple licenses in a drop down box, for example:

5 users - $20
10 users-  $50
20 users - $100

Once someone purchases a license, I got the $payment_amount passed from paypal and did an if, ifelse statement to generate the number of usernames accordingly.

I did not think about different currencies, therefore this technique won't work. Instead, I need to be able to assign an ID to each option in the drop down box and pass that instead.

I was wondering if this is possible and how I might go about doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily use any of the variables in the list of [HTML variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) to accomplish what you wish.

1. You could use invoice, and save the information to a database.
2. You could use on0 and os0 to define your own variables and price values.
3. You could define the 'custom' variable and set it to whatever your dreams desire.

All of them are equally effective, though the most commonly used method is probably #2.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="tester@test.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="asdfsafd">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="numUsers">numUsers</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="5 users">5 users $5.00</option>
    <option value="10 users">10 users $9.00</option>
    <option value="20 users">20 users $17.00</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="5 users">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="10 users">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="9.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="20 users">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="17.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: This will assign a value to each option in the drop down, yes. But I need to be able to ONLY post the option selected as i'm using a PHP if statement to determine how many users I should email.

Comment: Try that code, click submit, you will see that only one of the option values, "5 users", "10 users", or "20 users" will actually be submitted.  ----  on0=numUsers&os0=[whatever you select, and only the one that you select]   ---- your PHP script should ignore the prices listed, or if you're posting the data to your script, then to PayPal, create the prices and send that with the POST to PayPal.